# core-pages confilct with paper-input not rendering

Tags: polymer

When using core-pages paper-input are not displayed.

```
<core-pages  selected="{{selected}}">
    <section id="page1">
      <paper-input value="{{origin}}" label="Origin"></paper-input>
      <div>
        A: {{origin}}
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="page2">
      <div>2</div>
    </section>
  </core-pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly adjusted your example and put it on jsfiddle and as a snipped here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kreide/e13jme4y/

```html
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/core-elements.html">
<polymer-element name="my-core-pages" attributes="selected" noscript>
    <template>
        <style>
            core-pages {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            core-pages > section {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                border-radius: inherit;
            }
        </style>
        <core-pages selected={{selected}}>
            <section id="page1">
                <paper-input value="{{origin}}" label="Origin"></paper-input>
                <div>A: {{origin}}</div>
            </section>
            <section id="page2">
                <div>2</div>
            </section>
        </core-pages>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
<my-core-pages selected="0"></my-core-pages>
```

Paper-input is displayed correctly as you can see. Not setting the `selected` property, or not importing the paper-input.html might lead to your described behaviour.